# in Oracle Autonomous database try to create an workspace in the plsql program by using the apex_util.create_user. but failed

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-autonomous-db, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

```
    APEX_UTIL.SET_SECURITY_GROUP_ID( APEX_UTIL.FIND_SECURITY_GROUP_ID( p_workspace => 'teacher' ));

   apex_util.create_user(
   p_user_name => 'teacher',
   p_web_password => 'ChangeMe@1234',
   p_developer_privs => 'ADMIN:CREATE:DATA_LOADER:EDIT:HELP:MONITOR:SQL',
   p_email_address => 'test1@example.com',
   p_default_schema => 'teacher',
   p_change_password_on_first_use => 'N' );

   end;
```

```
Error report -
ORA-20001: Package variable g_security_group_id must be set.
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210100.WWV_FLOW_API", line 485
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210100.WWV_FLOW_API", line 520
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210100.WWV_FLOW_FND_USER_INT", line 1731
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210100.HTMLDB_UTIL", line enter code here  1245
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

does the Oracle Autonomous database allow developer to create apex workspace via the programming method?
any API available?
Does the OCI for Java SDK support the creation of APEX?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I execute the plsql statement in the sql developer which has no oci-java-cloud plugin.

Answer (score 4):

To add workspaces to your APEX instance, please use the [ADD_WORKSPACE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aeapi/ADD_WORKSPACE-Procedure.html#GUID-A5901582-5A5D-4273-9795-7D203E616C1A) procedure.

Example:

```
BEGIN
    APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.ADD_WORKSPACE (
        p_workspace_id       => 8675309,
        p_workspace          => 'MY_WORKSPACE',
        p_primary_schema     => 'SCOTT',
        p_additional_schemas => 'HR:OE' );
END;
```

To create [APEX users on Autonomous Database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/apex-access-admin-services.html#GUID-D078638E-4F59-46CA-A14D-DAEBE1514BE8), please note:

> Application Express Administration Services and the Oracle Application
> Express development environment on Autonomous Database use Database
> Accounts authentication. This authentication method uses the database
> account user name and password to authenticate users.

Comment: BEGIN
    APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.ADD_WORKSPACE (
        p_workspace          => 'TEACHER',
        p_primary_schema     => 'TEACHER');
END;

Comment: I am able to run the script above and "TEACHER" workspace can be created. I also create the TEACHER database user. But i can not sign-into the workspace with the TEACHER workspace name, TEACHER account along with the TEACHER database password. I am able to sign into the database action with the teacher account.

Comment: That is reason why i try to use apex_util.create_user to create apex user.

Comment: The APEX environment on Autonomous use Database Accounts Authentication. Please take a look at this useful blog post:
https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/how-to-script-workspace-provisioning-on-oracle-autonomous-database

Comment: I tried the steps in the blog, but does not work . did anyone in the community try to create a workspace in the ATP by using the plsql program not just the document?

Comment: Jian - That script works fine if you run it using an APEX app. I believe you wish to create those users programmatically.

Comment: Thank for you the comment. I just try to execute the script in the sql developer or Autonomous database action. Can i do that?

Comment: Jian - At the moment is not possible to run it using Database Actions.